# CSS positioning Internet Explorer vs. Chrome/Firefox/Safari menu position. Doing my head in

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, tags

Please have a look at http://bestofyoutube.com. Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong here?

Seems like the IE (version 7+8) put the menu a lot further down then what Safari/Chrome/Firefox do. The little pic I have to the right when people log is also completely thrown out of the normal standard in Internet Explorer (The others worked fine).

Screen shot on IE:

[image]

Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: You could make a conditional stylesheet and increase the height for just IE. But that's a last-resort solution for me.

Comment: The conditional stylesheet idea is a good one, but without knowing what your actual CSS is it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting bug in IE. To be quickly fixed you need to add in your `stylesheet.css` this code:

```
body {
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:8px;
}
```

In good to iterate over the options with top padding, removing it from the body.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works beautifully when I have it on the development server, then when I upload it to the web server it's a completely different result and back to square one again?!? Strange.. any ideas

Comment: Shift + refresh (sometimes twice) to ensure you bypass browser cache and see latest version of all files.  If that fails try renaming css file and edit code that loads css to match new name.

Comment: Thanks for help, but still the same problem unfortunately

Comment: Try to remove all spaces and line breaks before `<!doctype>`

Answer (score 1):

I think IE tries to draw invisible borders for your menu table.
Try to disable borders for this table.
And don't forget about table cells padding/margin.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have to do a conditional stylesheet just as you mention.